# List Comprehension Control Flow

Tags: python, list-comprehension, control-flow

I am trying to utilize list comprehension to recreate the results of a function that involves multiple `elif` statements.

My program is currently like this

```
import numpy as np  

def myFunction(x):
    result = []
    for num in x:
        if num <= 0.5:
            result.append(1)
        elif num <= 0.75:
            result.append(2)
        elif num <= 0.9:
            result.append(3)
        else:
            result.append(4)

    return result

u = np.random.uniform(0,1,1000)

myFunction(u)
```

This program produces a list of 1,2,3 or 4 with the appropriate probabilities. I was wondering if there is a way I could utilize list comprehension to perform the same task.

Let's say I was given a vector `x = [1,2,3,4]`, my desired outcomes,  and `Prob = [0.5,0.75,0.9,1.0]`, the cumulative probability that the ith event will occur. How can I use list comprehension get a similar result?

I was trying to do something like

```
[x[i] for num in u for i, test in enumerate(Prob) if num <= test]
```

but this returns all of the elements of `x` where `num <= test` and I only want the first one.

I hope this makes since and thanks for any help.

Comment: If you only want the first occurrence you could wrap your list comprehension with a `next` function call, e.g.: `next(x[i] for num in u for i, test in enumerate(Prob) if num <= test)`. Although I have to admit i am not quite sure if I understood what you want correctly

Comment: Lines of Code has never been a good metric of software for almost any purpose. As it happens, your top code block runs significantly faster and is vastly more readable than the proposed answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `next(iterable)` to great effect: `next(outcome for outcome, prob in zip(x, Prob) if num <= prob)` will compute the same number as the body of your for-loop:

```
def myFunction2(x):
    outcomes = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    probs = [0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 1.0]
    result = []
    for num in x:
        o = next(o for o, p in zip(outcomes, probs) if num <= p)
        result.append(o)
    return result
```

Of course, we can pepper this up with a list comprehension to make the entire function a bit shorter:

```
def myFunction3(x):
    outcomes = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    probs = [0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 1.0]
    result = [
        next(o for o, p in zip(outcomes, probs) if num <= p)
        for num in x
    ]
    return result
```

Comment: Very clever, and unreadable, and about 6x slower than the chained ifs of the original post. I figured the zip and the two nested for loops would cost you, so I tested it.

Comment: If speed matters, use Joran Beasley's NumPy-based solution. If you want to solve the problem using iterators (which is roughly what the asker wanted), then use this solution instead.

Answer (score 4):

typically probabilities sum to 1.0 ie  `probs = [0.5,0.25,0.15,0.1]`

you can then do something really easy

```
numpy.random.choice([1,2,3,4],p=probs)
```

if it was me this is the solution I would use ;P